Using generateStaticParams function in Next.js 14, I'm not able to cache to my page
I am using Next.js 14 and my folder is like this:

In page.tsx:
export const dynamicParams = true;
export const revalidate = 3600; 

export function generateStaticParams() { 
  return [
    {"slug":["artificial-intelligence-course-training"]},
    {"slug":["machine-learning-training"]}, 
    {"slug":["salesforce-training"]},
    {"slug":["salesforce-tutorial"]},
    {"slug":["aws-training"]},
    {"slug":["forescout-administrator-training"]},
    {"slug":["what-is-cloud-computing"]}
]
}

I am trying this and build to my application. Here is my dynamic static html file:

When I deploy to my code in Vercel then check to my header then it shows like this:

My header is X-Vercel-Cache: MISS. It always shows a miss, how can I get it to cache?

why is it an array inside the slug. isnt it like {"slug":"artificial-intelligence-course-training"}

Yes this is my slug and it's more slug it's Dynamic
